# Solve $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos \left(x\right)\sqrt{\cos \left(2x\right)}\cdot \sqrt[3]{\cos \left(3x\right)}}{x^2}\right)$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos \left(x\right)\sqrt{\cos \left(2x\right)}\cdot \sqrt[3]{\cos \left(3x\right)}}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: It seems to be a case where Taylor series would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Near $x=0$, we have
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right),$$
\begin{align}\sqrt{\cos(2x)} &= \sqrt{1-\frac{4x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)} \\
&= 1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{4x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right),
\end{align}
\begin{align}\left(\cos(3x)\right)^{1/3} &= \left(1-\frac{9x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)^{1/3} \\
&= 1-\frac{1}{3}\frac{9x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right),
\end{align}
and then
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(2x)}\left(\cos(3x)\right)^{1/3}}{x^2} &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)\left(1-x^2+O\left(x^4\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{3x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)}{x^2} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1- \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}-x^2-\frac{3x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)}{x^2} \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^2+O\left(x^4\right)}{x^2} \\
&= 3+\lim_{x\to 0}O\left(x^2\right) \\
&= 3.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-(\cos^6x\cos^32x\cos^23x)^{1/6}}{x^2}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos^6x\cos^32x\cos^23x}{x^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1{1+\sum_{r=1}^5(\cos^6x\cos^32x\cos^23x)^{r/6}}$$

The second limit converges to $\dfrac1{1+\sum_{r=1}^51^{r/6}}=\dfrac16$

For the first, $\cos^6x=(1-\sin^2x)^3=1-3\sin^2x+\cdots$

$\cos^32x=(1-2\sin^2x)^3=1-6\sin^2x+\cdots$

and $\cos^23x=\dfrac{1+\cos6x}2=\dfrac{1+4\cos^32x-3\cos2x}2=\dfrac{1+4\{(1-2\sin^2x)\}^3-3(1-2\sin^2x)}2=1-9\sin^2x+\cdots$

as $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$

Comment: @nedeljkosstevo, So, the limit $$=\dfrac{6+3+9}6=\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Easy to know:
$$(\cos kx)^{1/k}=1-k·x^2/2+o(x^2).$$
Obviously 
$$1-\cos x(\cos（2x）^1/2)(\cos（3x）^1/3)=1-(1-x^2/2)(1-x^2)(1-3x^2/2)+o(x^2).$$
So  the limit $=1/2+1+3/2=3$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your text on this site, since it will make your contributions a lot easier to read.

Comment: I added LaTeX and slightly modified the presentation, without changing your answer. Please let me know if you are satisfied with it or not.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you very much，I’m not skilled at using the website,I’m freshman

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ as $x\to0$,
- $(1+t)^a=1+at+o(t)$ as $t\to0$